# Write to several database in Redis for python

Tags: python, database, redis, key-value-store

I want to write some values into different database, this is my code:

```
import redis

r1 = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db = 'db1')
r2 = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db = 'db2')

numList = ['4', '3', '2', '1']

for num in numList:
   r1.lpush('a', num)
   r2.lpush('a', 'test')

print r1.lrange('a',start=0,end=-1)
print r2.lrange('a',start=0,end=-1)
```

Then I got this result:

```
['test', '1', 'test', '2', 'test', '3', 'test', '4']
['test', '1', 'test', '2', 'test', '3', 'test', '4']
```

Although I use different database, but for the same key, all the value is put in.
Thank you.

Answer (score 29):

DBs are supposed to be [zero-based numeric index](http://redis.io/commands/select) <s>(apperently the limit is 15)</s>. Try using

```
r1 = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db = 0)
r2 = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db = 1)
```

Comment: You help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I use almost the same code redis_server = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True, db=0)

Comment: There is no limit of 15 databases. You can set the number of databases in the redis.config file to the number you want and then select the dbid between 0 and 'databases'-1.

Comment: @MikeL I wrote this answer almost 6 years ago. I don't remember exactly why I wrote about this limit. Perhaps there was such limit back then but it's not here anymore. Who knows? I don't remember.